# How to retrieve data from oracle to R in a faster way than this?

Tags: r, oracle, dbi

Here is the data frame  that i have

```
trail_df= data.frame(d= seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-02-01"), by= 1),
                      AA= NA,
                      BB= NA,
                      CC= NA)
```

Now I would loop to the columns of trail_df and get the data of the column names respectively from the oracle database for the given date, which I am doing like this.

```
for ( i in 2:ncol(trail_df)){
      c_name = colnames(trail_df)[i]
      query = paste0("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ID= '",c_name,"' ")   # this query would return Date and price
      result= dbGetQuery(con, query)              # con is the connection variable from db
      
      for (k in nrow(trail_df)){
          trail_df [which(as.Date(result[k,1])==as.Date(trail_df[,1])),i]= result[k,2]
          # just matching the date in trail_df dataframe and pasting the value in front of respective column
  }
}
```

this is the snippet of the code and the dates filtering and all has been taken care of in real code.

The problem is, I have more than 6000 columns and 500 rows, for which I have to match the dates(
BECAUSE THE DATES ARE RANDOM) and put the price in front, which is taking like forever now.

I am new in the R language and would appreciate any help which would fasten this code maybe multiprocess if possible in R.

Comment: I would querry all `c_name`s simultaneously. Doing thousands of querries must be inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps to this answer:

1. Use parameterized queries to get the raw data; and
2. Get this data into the "wide" format you desire.

### Parameterized query

My (first) suggestion is to use [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries), which is safer. It may not improve the speed relative to @RonakShah's answer (using `sprintf`), at least not on the first time.

However, it might help *a touch* if the query is repeated: DBMSes tend to parse/optimize queries and cache this optimization. When a query changes even a little, this caching cannot happen, and the query is re-optimized. In this case, this cache-invalidation is unnecessary, and can be avoided if we use binding parameters.

```r
query <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ID IN (%s)",
                 paste(rep("?", ncol(trail_df[-1])), collapse = ","))
query
# [1] "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ID IN (?,?,?)"
res <- dbGetQuery(con, query, params = list(trail_df$ID))
```

Some thoughts:

- if the database has many more dates than what you have here, you can restrict the data returned by reducing the date range queries. This will work well if your `trail_df` dates are close together:

  ```r
  query <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ID IN (%s) and Date between ? and ?",
                   paste(rep("?", ncol(mtcars)), collapse = ","))
  query
  res <- dbGetQuery(con, query, params = c(list(trail_df$ID), as.list(range(df$d))))
  ```
- if your dates are more variable and you end up querying many more rows than you actually need, I suggest you can upload your `trail_df` dates into a temporary table and something like:

  ```r
  "select tb.Date, tb.ID, tb.Price
     from mytemptable tmp
     left join tablename tb on tmp.d = tb.Date
   where ..."
  ```

### Reshape

It appears as if your database table may be more "long" shaped and you want it "wide" in your frame. There are many ways to reshape from long-to-wide ([examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+reshape%20long%20to%20wide)), but these should work:

```r
reshape2::dcast(res, Date ~ ID, value.var = "Price") # 'Price' is the 'value' column, unk here

tidyr::pivot_wider(res, id_cols = "Date", names_from = "ID", values.from = "Price")
```